# Java not choosing the most specific method when called through a generic wrapper?

Tags: java, generics, implicit-conversion

According to this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5, the Java compiler will attempt to choose the most specific method to invoke when multiple applicable and accessible ones are available. The intuition is that more specific method can be substituted by less specific ones but not vice versa.

So I'm a bit surprised that this won't work when we wrap the ambiguous call within a generic wrapper as follows:

```
public class Test{
        static <T> void direct(T t) { System.out.println("generic");}
        static void direct(int t) { System.out.println("specific-int");}

        static <T> void indirect(T t) { direct(t);}
        
        public static void main ( String [] args ) {
            direct(1);    // print specific-int
            indirect(1);  // print generic
        }
     }
```

So we can see that just calling `direct` makes it works as expected. But when calling `indirect`, the less specific method is called instead.

The behavior changes if I change the type of the direct method as such

```
    static void direct(short t) { System.out.println("specific-short");}
```

In this case both lines print `generic` instead (the `short` method isn't called in either case), which tells me that the literal `1` was implicitly casted to `int` in the first instance. If that's the case, why wasn't it called with the more specific method that takes in `int` as an argument?

Comment: Generics only work with objects as of now.

Comment: oh so the literal will be converted to the Integer class when called with `indirect`? Which then can only be called with the generic method and not the one that takes `int`?

Comment: That is called autoboxing and yes.

Comment: "which tells me that the literal 1 was implicitly casted to int in the first instance" No, literal 1 is already an int. There is no casting.

Comment: Because of (Type Erasure)[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html] Java compiler will replace generic types with `Object`. When you will pass `int` value type to the `Object` reference type it will be boxed(converted from value type to reference type) It means that it will be converted to `Integer`. The most suitable method for `Integer` reference type is `direct(Object t)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 unrelated reasons, both of which lead to the generic version:

### Boxing

type parameters are neccessarily subtypes of Object (for now, Project Valhalla is a java update in the pipeline that may change this somewhat).

Hence, the `direct(t)` call in your `indirect` method cannot possibly treat `direct(int)` as the most specific version of it, as the `t` parameter in `indirect` cannot possibly be an `int`.

Specifically, when you invoke `indirect(1)`, that 1 is an `int` which isn't a valid value for `indirect` (as `indirect`'s parameter is of type `T`; T is a type parameter with as lower bound `java.lang.Object`, and `1` isn't a valid value for `Object`).

However, java *also* has the concept of 'boxing', where primitives will be converted to their boxed type automatically, but only if the code wouldn't have compiled otherwise. You can see this with `javap` - you'll notice that the compiler replaced `1` with `Integer.valueOf(1)` to make it work.

### Names are compile-time

Which method is chosen is **locked in at compile time**. Note that overrides (where a subtype implements the exact same method, i.e. if that method is annotated with `@Override`, the compiler will accept it) **are entirely a runtime thing** and java always picks the implementation from the subtype, but `static` doesn't "do" subtyping, so it's not relevant here.

The 2 `direct` methods you have are not the same; at the JVM level, they have completely different names, so this is **just** about which of the 2 `direct` methods is picked by `javac`, hence, compile time is the only time that matters here.

Let me make that clear: **The 2 `direct` methods do not have the same name, therefore at runtime the JVM *does not have the freedom* to pick one or the other depending on types. For the same reason it can't replace a call to `foo()` with a call to `bar()` - not the same name**.

`indirect`, the method, has no idea what T is. **Therefore it could not possibly call `direct(int)` even if the boxing thing wasn't the case!** - looking up which of the two `direct` methods to pick is **not** done at runtime.

### To reiterate

Given:

```
public class Parent {
  void foo(int i) { System.out.println("Parent-int"); }
  void foo(Integer i) { System.out.println("Parent-Integer"); }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    void foo(int i) { System.out.println("Child-int"); }
}

...

Parent p = new Child();
p.foo(5); // prints Child-int
p.foo(Integer.valueOf(5)); // prints Parent-Integer
```

### a final note

You wrote in a comment:

> "which tells me that the literal 1 was implicitly casted to int in the first instance"

No. integer literals in java **are `int`** - the java lang spec defines them as such. You can write `short x = 5;` only because of a special exemption rule that states you don't need the cast there, but languagewise, all non-decimal-pointed (and non `0x0p` form) numeric AST nodes are treated as `int`. They are THEN implicitly casted if e.g. a `long` is needed.

You can ask javac to treat things as long by sticking a capital L at the end. Given:

```
void foo(byte i) {System.out.println("byte");
void foo(short i) {System.out.println("short");
void foo(int i) {System.out.println("int");
void foo(long i) {System.out.println("long");

foo(5); // prints 'int'
foo(5L); // prints 'long'
```

Even though '5' fits in 'byte', it is an int, and hence the `int` variant is chosen.

Comment: thank you this answer really gets to the root of it, while also explains another relevant Java concept. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> why wasn't it called with the more specific method that takes in int as an argument?

The Java compiler decides which method to invoke at compile time. That is, for the `indirect` method, it chooses an overload of `direct` which can be safely invoked for all invocations of `indirect`.

The only such overload is the `direct(T)` method: this accepts any `Object` parameter, as does `indirect(T)`. It can't invoke `direct(int)` because not all `Object`s are `Integer`s.

`indirect` doesn't do anything different when invoked with an `int` parameter.